# Static variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables, static-variables

In C#, is there a way to put a static variable in a method like VB.Net?

```
Static myCollection As Collection
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why doesn't C# support static method
>   variables?
>
> Q: In C++, it's possible to write a
>   static method variable, and have a
>   variable that can only be accessed
>   from inside the method. C# doesn't
>   provide this feature. Why?
>
> A: There are two reasons C# doesn't
>   have this feature.
>
> First, it is possible to get nearly
>   the same effect by having a
>   class-level static, and adding method
>   statics would require increased
>   complexity.
>
> Second, method level statics are
>   somewhat notorious for causing
>   problems when code is called
>   repeatedly or from multiple threads,
>   and since the definitions are in the
>   methods, it's harder to find the
>   definitions.
>
> -- [msdn c# faq](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/11/130248.aspx)

Comment: > "notorious for causing problems when code is called repeatedly or from multiple threads" -- Funny, because the VB.Net implementation is considered to be thread-safe.

Comment: How did this get Checked as the best answer.  The answer is simply NO.  It is said, but still a no.  The Answer provided here which are a quote from Eric Gunnerson are Mircosoft's cop-out. It is useful simple as that.

BTW, Java has had this ability since at least 1.2 and C++ for as long as I can remember. You would think a language that mixes C++, Java and VB would support for the things that all three of them had in common. If three languages support this there must be a good reason, and dropping it with those two reasons is lame and the they obviously are hiding something.

Comment: Regardless of the excuse, this is still the canonical answer that is given by Microsoft.

Comment: just make a 1 method static class with a private static variable. and if you really want your static method in a class with other stuff then have your static method call this new method.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't but how is this different then having a static variable at the class level?

[Actually if you look](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/pages/7717.aspx) into how shared is implemented, it is a compiler trick that creates a static field on the class.

Comment: Yep, it's exactly the same as having one at class level. It's only allowed to be declared at method level because legacy VB's static keyword meant a local's value would persist after function/sub return.

Comment: It's different because VB's "compiler trick" also uses the monitor class to make sure it's thread safe, and because it's scoped to method so access elsewhere will fail (better semantics).

Comment: Its only scoped because the method name is used to name the variable. And I'd assume if you wanted it threadsafe in C# you'd implement a monitor as well. I'd rather see C# implement a static thread safe that wraps access to the variable as they do in VB, but not worry about scoping to a method.

Comment: in VB6 was a static method variable shared accross all instances of a class or scoped to the actual class?

Comment: In VB a "static" variable is scoped like the method. So if the method is shared (C# static) so is the variable. If it is inside an instance method, then it is owned by a specific object.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to VB.NET's [`Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8(VS.80).aspx) is to create a field in the current type.  Other than that C# has no equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No, The CLR does not support this, and VB.NET resorts to compiler tricks to allow it. Ugh.

Comment: If you don't like compiler tricks, do you use the "yield" keyword in C#?

Comment: How is it a compiler trick? It is just a member variable that happens to have a reduced visibility.

Comment: I also never use yield.  I would like static variable methods though

Answer (score -6):

I'm pretty sure the C# equivalent is `const`: therefore:

```
public const Collection myCollection = new Collection();
```

I'm not too familiar with VB.NET, so I could be off base, but that will allow you set a variable which cannot be changed.

Comment: static variables are not constant.  A static variable is one where each instance of the class shares the same variable instance.  The variable is mutable, and a change to the value in one class will change the value in all other instances of that class.

Comment: Slight correction. A static variable in C# is shared. In VB a static variable is only shared if the containing function is shared.