# Initialize value inside function only once

Tags: c#, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static variables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840397/static-variables-in-c)

If you have a large function and in the middle somewhere you have a value that should be declared only the first time its encounter.

In c++ you can use static for this:

```
void func() {
  ...
  ...
  static double startPosition = 0.0;
  int var = startPositino - value;
  startPosition = var;
  ...
}
```

But in c# you cant have static variables inside a function, is there some other way to do this without declaring it outside the function?

Comment: “If you have a large function” That's your problem right there.

Comment: The question is not why c# does not allow static variables inside a function

Comment: Does it make a difference to you if it's a `private static` field? That's the best you can do in C#.

Comment: @Merni: The accepted answer at the linked question tells you that what you want is impossible. The closest "equivalent" to method statics are class statics.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool changed = true;



void func() // the large function from the question (it wasn't specified what it does or what is called)
{
   .....

   if(changed)
   {
       // here you initalize you variable (the static from the c++)
       changed = false;
   }

   .....
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. What is the return type of `largeFunction()`? And how does it even relate to the question?

Comment: The code sample does succeed in demonstrating the general concept of how this could be accomplished in C# - downvoting because it doesn't compile "out of the box" is pretty harsh.

Comment: I didn't donwnvote because of the compile error. But because the answer doesn't actually answer anything. It's just a code sample without any explanation an it's not obvious what does it have to do with the question.

Comment: In your "large function" (as a hint: try to break your "large function" in smaller chunks of code ...multiple methods it would be easier) place a condition where: if the declared bool from the beggining is true ... initialize the variable. after that switch it to false and the variable will initialize only once